# How to get Category Count Use at News in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hello guys I have problem to get count of category use in news

for example i wanna know "international" category how many use in news

this is my News Entity:

```
 public class News
    {
        public int NewsId { get; set; }
       
        public int? SubGroup { get; set; }

        public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
        public string NewsBody { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string Poster { get; set; }
       
        public DateTime? UpdateTime { get; set; }
        public bool  isChoseClerck{ get; set; }

        public News()
        {
            this.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        //RelationShip
        public List<Category>  Category { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public string Source{ get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my Dto that i wanna show to user :

```
 public class SubCategoryWithCountDTO
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CateGoryName { get; set; }
        public int UseCount { get; set; }
    }
```

ive wrote below service bu i didnt know that i cant use lambda in "include"

```
 public async Task<List<SubCategoryWithCountDTO>> SubCategoryWithCount(int skip, int take)
        {
            var subCategoryList = await _context.Categories
                .Where(x => x.ParentId != null).OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId)
                .Skip(skip).Take(take).ToListAsync();
            var SubCategoryWithCount = new List<SubCategoryWithCountDTO>();
            foreach (var item in subCategoryList)
            {
                var categoryUse = _context.News.Include(x => x.Category
                    .Select(x => x.CategoryId == item.CategoryId)).Count();
                var preSubCategory = new SubCategoryWithCountDTO
                {
                    CategoryId = item.CategoryId,
                    CateGoryName = item.CateGoryName,
                    UseCount = categoryUse
                };
                SubCategoryWithCount.Add(preSubCategory);
            }

            return SubCategoryWithCount;
        }
```

can someone show me right way ?, thanks

Comment: Can you share an example result and your object list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve your goal this way:

```
public List<TagWithUseCountViewModel> GetTagWithCount()
    {

        var list = new List<TagWithUseCountViewModel>();

        var query = from item in _context.News.SelectMany(x => x.Tags)
                    select item;

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            list.Add(new TagWithUseCountViewModel
            {

                Id = item.Id,
                TagName = item.TagName,
                UseCount =
                query.Where(x => x.Id == item.Id).GroupBy(x => x.NewsList).Count()
            });
        } }
```